# How to align components within a html strip

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a newsletter subscription strip above the footer and I am having major issues styling it. Basically I require:

1: all the components to be vertically aligned and to be aligned with each other

2: The sign up field to be on the right hand side of the strip

3: My client is away but he explicitly says:  copy: ‘ Join Balance and get 20% off your first order’ Use Balance Coffee GIF here to add next to text. Not sure where best to put it but as a bonus if someone has any ideas where I should put this gif, will be much appreciated.

Here is the strip:

[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<!-- newsletter section -->

<div class="newsletter_section">

<div class="newsletter_text_section">
<p>Join Balance and get 20% off your first order</p>
</div>

<div class="newsletter_gif_section">
<img src="./wp-content/uploads/2020/07/test-image.gif" alt="Balance Newsletter" style="height:100px;">
</div>

<div class="newsletter_input_section">
<div class="klaviyo-form-X95HYK"></div> 
</div>
    
</div>

.newsletter_section{
    width:100% !important;
    background: #455657;
      overflow:hidden;
      padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px
}

.newsletter_text_section {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:30px;
    height: 10vh;
  line-height: 10vh;
}

.newsletter_text_section p {
    font-size:24px !important;
}

.newsletter_gif_section {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
        height: 10vh;
  line-height: 10vh;
}

.newsletter_input_section {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
        height: 10vh;
  line-height: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: There is no input inside `.newsletter_input_section`. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that anyone can understand your problem better.

Comment: It's link with Klaviyo. I think we just need to move the div with class `"klaviyo-form-X95HYK"`

Comment: It hasn't made any difference

Comment: add `display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;` on `newsletter_input_section`

Comment: and to align all element vertically center use `display:flex;
    align-items: center;` on `.newsletter_section`

Comment: @decpk Sweet, that moved the input field and button to the right hand side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234886/discussion-between-decpk-and-bruceybandit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following style on `.newsletter_section`

```
display:flex;
align-items: center;
```

and follwing style on `.newsletter_input_section`

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        
.newsletter_section{
    width:100% !important;
    background: #455657;
      overflow:hidden;
      padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px
}

.newsletter_text_section {
  width: 40%; color: #fff;
  float: left;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:30px;
      line-height: 10vh;
}

.newsletter_text_section p {
    font-size:24px !important;
}

.newsletter_gif_section {
  width: 20%;
  float: left; color: #fff;
        height: 10vh;
  line-height: 10vh; 
}

.newsletter_input_section {
  width: 38%;  
  float: left;  color: #fff;
 
    
  line-height: 20vh;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="newsletter_section">

<div class="newsletter_text_section">
<p>Join Balance and get 20% off your first order</p>
</div>

<div class="newsletter_gif_section">
<img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/3193497924224721006" alt="Balance Newsletter" style="height:100px;">
</div>

<div class="newsletter_input_section">
<div class="klaviyo-form-X95HYK"> <input type="text" /> <button type="">Submit</button> </div> 
</div>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```